# Why does my send callback execute so quickly after calling Socket.BeginSend?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

When I send a considerable chunk of data to a *remote* machine, the send callback is executed almost immediately.

```
[05:10:35:981] ChildSocket.Send(): Sending 1048508 bytes.
[05:10:35:988] ChildSocket.SendCallback(): Sent 1048508 bytes.
```

There is no way that my internet is fast enough to successfully send near one mega byte in 7 milliseconds.

Because of this behaviour I am under the impression that calling BeginSend merely writes the send buffer to the operating system and the operating system will send it in due time.

Is this suspicion correct? Why does the send callback execute so quickly?

Comment: Keep in mind your internet has nothing to do with how long it takes to send, only how long it takes to arrive. Once your data is on the wire it is sent.

Comment: The documentation for [Socket.BeginSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9.aspx) does say: "The successful completion of a send does not indicate that the data was successfully delivered. If no buffer space is available within the transport system to hold the data to be transmitted, send will block unless the socket has been placed in nonblocking mode." Documentation for `Socket.Send` says the same thing. It also says: A successful completion of the Send method means that the underlying system has had room to buffer your data for a network send."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the OS buffers the data (although 1MB seem quite a lot). Send never guarantees you that data was received by the remote side. This holds true even without OS buffering. Either let the other side acknowledge the data or `Shutdown` the socket and wait until the connection is done.